# Regex: Matching till first, not last occurency

Tags: regex

I have a string like this:

```
BEGIN
blabla..
END;

BEGIN
one two    
END;
```

And I want to make regex that will find this parts separately.
I made regex `(?i)BEGIN[\s\S]*(?i)END;`
But it finds this string as one instance matching. But I need two. How to make it search `END;` for first occurency, not last ?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(?i)BEGIN[\s\S]*?(?i)END;
```

it's called lazy quantifier.

Answer (score 2):

You need a non-greedy `*`:

```
(?i)BEGIN[\s\S]*?(?i)END;
```

Note that regex cannot deal with nested BEGIN/END pairs. Better use a parser.

Comment: actually i made it for parsing PL/SQL and i hope it doesn't supports nesting :)